# How to access referer in getStaticProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to access the `referer` in `getStaticProps`; any way to access it? I know how to access with `getServerSideProps`, but not sure about `getStaticProps`.

With `getServerSideProps`: `context.req.headers.referer`;

JavaScript: `document.referer`;

How to achieve this with `getStaticProps`? If not possible, what is the best alternative?

```js
if (req.headers.referer === "https://example.com/") {
  return {
    Code
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props) runs at build time to generate static files. So when a user requests a page generated by it, there is no server-side code to run, so there is no way you could know the `referer` in it.

If this is important to you, you may wanna use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) and fetch data at request time after doing the validations you need. Or use a Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to run logic before your static or dynamic file is rendered:

```js
// middleware.ts at the same level as your pages folder

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(request.headers.get("referer"));
  // do stuff
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```